# Embedding a WPF Listbox to my WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, winforms-interop

How would I embed a WPF list box to my Windows Form application?

The WPF list box will ideally be able to add list box item objects, render the color (by setting the background property to some color brush), and display the content in the list box from a windows form text box.

I'm not looking to create a composite control in WPF, just embed a simple WPF list box in my Winforms solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [WPF Tutorial - Using WPF In WinForms](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms)

Comment: Thanks @Willem, it worked for the most part, however, I'm not sure of how to access that embedded list box in my program ........... Would I need to create some event handler to receive the request for the Winforms text box when a ListBoxItem is being sent to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your newly create `UserControl`, you can just expose the `ListBox` via a property. Then you can access the `ListBox` via the `UserControl`.

Somewhere in your UserControl.xaml.cs:

```
public ListBox MyListBox
{
    get
    {
        return {yourListBoxName};
    }
}
```

Then when you instantiated your new `UserControl`:

```
ElementHost elhost = new ElementHost();
elhost.Size = new Size(110, 60);
elhost.Location = new Point(45,35);

MyWPFControl wpfctl = new MyWPFControl();
elhost.Child = wpfctl;

this.Controls.Add(elhost);

//Access your ListBox via wpfctl.MyListBox
```

Alternatively you can have a look at [MVVM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/62da4a56-4699-494e-a47f-33b89eb9e8dd) and bind your `ListBox.ListBoxItem` to your `TextBox`;

Comment: Thanks @Willem, with this method I can now expose the ListBox properties in my user control. Question: What exactly are we returning where you've got "yourListBoxName"? This is what I've got:
<pre>
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        //public string yourListBoxName;
        public ListBox theListBox = new ListBox();
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ListBox MyListBox
        {
            get
            {
                return theListBox;
            }
        }

    }
<code>

Comment: @discofighter411 When you add your `ListBox` to your `WPF` `UserControl`, you give the `ListBox` a 'Name'. Then you use that name in the return of the property.

Comment: @Willem- Thanks, it renders just fine after that fix!